# (Django/Python) Error while deploying "chrnorm/deployment-action"

Tags: python, django, heroku

On GitHub I am trying to deploy a project to Herokuapp and I got this error during the "Create GitHub Deployment" stage of Deployment:

```
Run chrnorm/deployment-action@releases/v1
  with:
    initial_status: success
    token: ***
    target_url: https://***.herokuapp.com
    environment: production
  env:
    HEROKU_API_KEY: ***
    HEROKU_APP_NAME: ***
Error: HttpError: Resource not accessible by integration
Error: Resource not accessible by integration
```

Here are the requirements.txt

```
coverage>=5.3,<6.0
dj-database-url>=0.5.0
Django>=3.1.0,<4.0.0
gunicorn>=20.0.0,<21.0.0
psycopg2-binary>=2.8.0,<3.0.0
selenium>=3.141.0,<4.0.0
whitenoise>=5.2.0,<6.0.0
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong? Thank youuu

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same issue as you. What I needed to change were the permissions of the workflow/job. Documentation can be found here:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs

In my case I needed to configure the following:

```
deploy:
needs: build
runs-on: [self-hosted]
permissions: 
  deployments: write
  statuses: write
  contents: read
```